# Sharepoint 2013- I need a "Read More" link in a custom list were a multiple line column is used

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

The list contains large amount of text in a column and it would be nice to display the first 5 lines of text followed by a Read more link. I've seen examples of this for Sharepoint 2010 but not for 2013. Any ideas?
/Andreas

Comment: Where do you want to display a text ? in a web part?

Comment: Yes, it is in a webpart.

Comment: wow. people still use sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

Since the client side rendering (CSR) is the **default** rendering mode in SharePoint 2013, below is demonstrated how to customize Body field.

### How to customize SharePoint List View using client-side rendering (CSR)

Assume an `Announcements` list that contains `Body` column. The below example demonstrates how to *truncate* the content of `Body` field and display `Read more` link

[image]

**Solution**

A. Create a rendering template, lets name it `Announcemets.js`

```
  SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

  function bodyFieldRenderer(ctx) {
    var item = ctx.CurrentItem;
    var headline = $(ctx.CurrentItem.Body).text().substring(0,200);
    return String.format('{0}<br/><a href="{1}&ID={2}" class="ms-accentText">Read more...</a>',headline, ctx.displayFormUrl,ctx.CurrentItem.ID);  
  }

  function init() {

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

      Templates: {

           Fields: {
               "Body": {
                   View:bodyFieldRenderer,
               }
           }
      }
    });
  }



RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/announcements.js"), init);
  init();

});
```

B. Upload JavaScript file into `Site Assets` library

C. Open the page in Edit mode and specify for web part `JS Link` property:

```
~sitecollection/SiteAssets/announcements.js
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this - worked for me in SharePoint Online - but there needs to be a "script editor" webpart sitting above the announcements with the jquery script refs (and also the jquery downloaded and saved in the location):

```
<script language="javascript" src="~siteCollection/SiteAssets/scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="~siteCollection/SiteAssets/scripts/jquery.SPServices.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```